# Jenkins SVN poll overhead

Tags: jenkins

I think I remember reading that Jenkins doesn't advise you to poll SVN very often because it generates overhead. Instead, one should place a hook in the SVN commands.

How often can I safely set Jenkins to poll SVN? every minute? every 15s? To me it sounds it would just poll for a checksum and if it differs, then it does an SVN update. I don't think polling a checksum on SVN can have a negative impact on performance?

Comment: What is the upside of poling SVN? If there is no change, there is no need to poll. If there is, a hook will notify about it.

Comment: the upside is that I can configure poll frequency as separately for builds, and no need to manually go and hack svn post commit hooks

Comment: The recommendation to not poll only applies to environments where svn or jenkins run hot. For example, where I work we still poll and we have 1k builds polling every 3 minutes, but to do this, we have to run svn on flash cards (fusionIO), otherwise svn would die. If neither of svn or jenkins are running hot, then keep polling.

Answer (score 0):

Each poll will check for any update in the SVN URL of that particular job. You can set the polling frequency based on the normal checkin frequency. It will not have much impact over your system performance as it just checks for update. If you are concerned about the system performance, I would suggest you to go for `svn post commit hook` that can trigger the build. You can read more about this [Here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin)

Comment: Yes I know about the post commit hook, but I would like to not go and edit it on the svn side. If doing an SVN update every 10s is not too often and does not have adverse performance effects, then I would probably go with that.